# when to call super.onActivityResult?

Tags: java, android, overriding

When you are overriding methods in an Android activity, when do you need to call the `super.overridingMethod()` method and how do you know where to position that call (beginning, end, optional)? I write an android activity.

For example, `OnActivityResult` I see sometimes `super.onActivityResult` is called in the first line, some other times at the end of the body and sometimes not at all.

Answer (score 0):

Its depends on your need, if you want that Super class method will do some **important work for your child activity** then **call at first line** otherwise not required at first line,

if you are not interested in super class method() implementation, then you can call it anywhere, **but ideally we should give a chance to super class method implementation run very first.**

Comment: how can i know if i need activity method to run

Comment: If you are writer of super class then definitely you will know importance of super class method implementation. If its belong some API then its depend on API writer if its required the will provide you proper Document for the same.

Comment: That's mean if you are inheriting some class which is belong to some other vendor(You are not writer of that Class) then API vendor will provide you proper docx regarding to implementation of overriding method..

Comment: i understood the first time, but the android activity is unclear regarding these methods

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering this as well. If you subclassed `Activity`, the super method does the following:

```java
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    }
```

*Nothing.*

If you subclass `AppCompatActivity`, it subclasses `FragmentActivity`, which does:

```java
    /**
     * Dispatch incoming result to the correct fragment.
     */
    @Override
    @CallSuper
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        mFragments.noteStateNotSaved();
        int requestIndex = requestCode>>16;
        if (requestIndex != 0) {
            requestIndex--;

            String who = mPendingFragmentActivityResults.get(requestIndex);
            mPendingFragmentActivityResults.remove(requestIndex);
            if (who == null) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Activity result delivered for unknown Fragment.");
                return;
            }
            Fragment targetFragment = mFragments.findFragmentByWho(who);
            if (targetFragment == null) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Activity result no fragment exists for who: " + who);
            } else {
                targetFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode & 0xffff, resultCode, data);
            }
            return;
        }
        ActivityCompat.PermissionCompatDelegate delegate =
                ActivityCompat.getPermissionCompatDelegate();
        if (delegate != null && delegate.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
            // Delegate has handled the activity result
            return;
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); // This just calls that empty method above on `Activity`
    }
```

It will *'Dispatch incoming result to the correct fragment.'*. This is because you might have started the activity from a fragment, and without this, only the activity's `onActivityResult` is called back.

### So when should you call the super method?

In a fragment: It doesn't really matter, as your fragment will handle the result, and there is nothing else to do afterwards. You don't have to call the super method, as it would be empty.
In a FragmentActivity: If you override it in your activity which holds the fragment, then you should call the super method to pass the result to the fragment. You could do some logic before doing this if you want to, but I can't think of anything you'd want to do in the activity, instead of the fragment. I haven't written Android code much though.

**The ordering doesn't seem to matter, but in an FragmentActivity, I would stick to calling the super.onActivityResult after the Activity does its intermediary logic.**